# catch element that was #hash Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

**Example:**

if i go to google.com/#search

```
function checkHash(){ 
if(window.location.hash != hash) {
$("elementhashed").animate( { backgroundColor: "#ff4500" }, 1 ).animate( { backgroundColor: "FFF" }, 1500 );
hash = window.location.hash; 
} t=setTimeout("checkHash()",400); 
};
```

or if i go to google.com/#any hash

how to get the element http://URL/#elementID without defining a single element

**Example of single element:**

```
function checkHash(){ 
if(window.location.hash != hash) {
$(".body").animate( { backgroundColor: "#ff4500" }, 1 ).animate( { backgroundColor: "FFF" }, 1500 );
hash = window.location.hash; 
} t=setTimeout("checkHash()",400); 
};
```

Comment: [Try here](https://translate.google.com) Please elaborate on what's wrong? If you don't speak fluent english, they're other stack overflow sites in different languages

Comment: @MarleneOliveria Okay, are you trying to get the element that was in the hash. Like `http://URL/#elem`, get the element with the id `elem`?

Comment: `$(window.location.hash)` does that work? Animate it using: `$(window.location.hash).animate({/* CODE */})`

Comment: @MarleneOliveria PHP might be best. use `http://URL.com/?elem=testelem`. Then you could do: `$('#<?=$_REQUEST['elem'] ?>');`

Comment: my html code was in conflict with the hash, your first code worked, post a reply to I select it as best

Comment: hash means `id` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will get the hash and run it in jQuery. Basically, it will look for the element

```
$(window.location.hash);
```

To animate it, add `.animate()`

```
$(window.location.hash).animate({/* CODE */
    backgroundColor: '#ff4500'
}, 1);
```